# How to stop puppeteer follow redirects

Tags: chromium, puppeteer

Currently it seems the default behaviour of puppeteer is to follow redirects and return the DOM at the end of the chain.

How can I make the `.goto()` method to stop after the first redirect happened and simply return the html from that first 3xx page when i call page.content() method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can enable a request interception and abort additional requests if a chain of requests is identified:

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {
  if (request.isNavigationRequest() && request.redirectChain().length !== 0) {
    request.abort();
  } else {
    request.continue();
  }
});

await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');
```

Comment: Very nice dude. Is this in the new version? You made a colleague of mine very happy today

Comment: @Grant - This seems to catch ALL requests. How can I tell if it's the PAGE being redirected?

Comment: @TaeWoo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083776/how-is-defined-resourcetype-value-provided-by-the-devtool-protocol

Comment: Copy/Paste without attribution makes me :"( https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1132#issuecomment-393724933

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at the moment of writing, this is not possible (at least not in the high-level API that Puppeteer provides). Check out the docs for `goto` [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options).

Comment: Yes, its not possible with the high level api. logged an issue here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1132

Comment: Awesome. Great workaround! I thought about using the event handles, but I was not certain that it could be done, so I didn't want to potentially lead you down a blind path.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few modifications to the top answer and now we can track the specific status code number.

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.isNavigationRequest() && request.redirectChain().length >= 1) {
        const redirectResponse = request.redirectChain()[request.redirectChain().length - 1].response();
        request.respond({
            status: redirectResponse.status(),
            contentType: 'text/plain',
            body: 'Redirects!',
        });
    } else {
        request.continue();
    }
});
```